# PHP CURL sometimes return empty

Tags: php, curl

I want to ask something make me confuse.
I'am using CURL to get html code from this link

```
echo set_user_agent_grab("https://www.bandros.co.id/produk/dress-atasan-baju-rajut-wanita-sad-500");
```

And This is my function

```
function set_user_agent_grab($link){
    $headers = ["text/html; charset=UTF-8"];
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result;
    }
```

The problem, sometimes i got **return empty**, i dont know this is from my server or from the site protection with i dont know, please tell me, thank you.

Comment: I wonder how this would run anyway, because `$ch` is undefined

Comment: sorry i'am forgot, i've been edit my function by add $ch = curl_init();

Comment: Using `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch))`, `var_dump(curl_errno($ch))` and `var_dump(curl_error($ch))` after calling `curl_exec()` may give you some insight, at the moment you're not looking at any response state information, just the body.

Comment: _sometimes i got **return empty**_ -- hmm, how often it happens? could you output the `var_dump`s suggested by @Scuzzy in the comment above to at least track on what occasion it returns empty. I believe this can be the target server did not want to answer your request.

Comment: var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)) and get resource(1) of type (Unknown), what this mean ?

Answer (score 1):

CURLOPT_VERBOSE should reveal what happened. so just check if curl_exec fail, and if it does, throw a RuntimeException, then, next time it happens, check your php error logs. additionally you can check what curl_errno() and curl_error says.

```
function set_user_agent_grab($link) {
    $headers = [ 
            "text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
    ];
    $ch = curl_init ();
    $debugfileh = tmpfile ();
    $debugfile = stream_get_meta_data ( $debugfileh ) ['uri'];
    try {
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $debugfileh);

        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2' );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip' );
        $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
        if (! is_string ( $result )) {
            $errstr = "curl_exec failed: " . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ": " . curl_error ( $ch ) . ". debuginfo: " . file_get_contents ( $debugfile );
            throw new RuntimeException ( $errstr );
        }
        return $result;
    } finally{
        fclose ( $debugfileh );
        curl_close ( $ch );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks before mr @hanshenrik, I do not see any error on the error_log file and does it possibly affect the cookies of the website? if from cookies how to use it?

Comment: @CSMMedia libcurl doesn't use any cookies by default, every time this code runs, it starts fresh without any cookies.  but is your error logging broken then? you should fix your error logging before debugging this further. as a simple testcase, run `<?php throw new \Exception("error log test");` , and see if you can find `error log test` in your error logs... can you?

Comment: ok, thank you very much for helping but iam very curios even i using cronjob to run script every 5 minute and i not getting error in error_log, can we discuss privately so i can share my all code to you, I really appreciate if you can help me, please.

Comment: @CSMMedia sure, try facebook. contact details on my profile.